# AES Bouncy Castle- invalid parameter passed to AES init - org.bouncycastle.crypto.params.ParametersWithIV

Tags: java, security, encryption, aes, bouncycastle

I am trying to Encrypt and Decrypt using Bouncy castle. I am getting below error. How to fix or is there any better way to encrypt and decrypt using Bouncy castle

> Exception in thread "main" java.security.InvalidKeyException: invalid parameter passed to AES init - org.bouncycastle.crypto.params.ParametersWithIV
>       at org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.symmetric.util.BaseBlockCipher.engineInit(Unknown Source)
>       at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(Cipher.java:1394)
>       at com.test.PBE.encrypt(PBE.java:39)
>       at com.test.PBE.main(PBE.java:26)

This is my code

```
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.security.Security;

import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import javax.crypto.SecretKeyFactory;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.PBEKeySpec;

import org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider;

public class PBE {

private static final String salt = "A long, but constant phrase that will be used each time as the salt.";
private static final int iterations = 2000;
private static final int keyLength = 256;
private static final SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();

public static void main(String [] args) throws Exception {
    Security.insertProviderAt(new BouncyCastleProvider(), 1);

    String passphrase = "The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy brown dog";
    String plaintext = "hello world";
    byte [] ciphertext = encrypt(passphrase, plaintext);
    String encryptedText=ciphertext.toString();
    System.out.println("text::"+encryptedText);

    String recoveredPlaintext = decrypt(passphrase, encryptedText);

    System.out.println(recoveredPlaintext);
}

private static byte [] encrypt(String passphrase, String plaintext) throws Exception {
    SecretKey key = generateKey(passphrase);

    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CTR/NOPADDING");
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, generateIV(cipher), random);
    return cipher.doFinal(plaintext.getBytes());
}

private static String decrypt(String passphrase, String encryptedText) throws Exception {
    byte[] ciphertext=encryptedText.getBytes();
    SecretKey key = generateKey(passphrase);

    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CTR/NOPADDING");
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, generateIV(cipher), random);
    return new String(cipher.doFinal(ciphertext));
}

private static SecretKey generateKey(String passphrase) throws Exception {
    PBEKeySpec keySpec = new PBEKeySpec(passphrase.toCharArray(), salt.getBytes(), iterations, keyLength);
    SecretKeyFactory keyFactory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBEWITHSHA256AND256BITAES-CBC-BC");
    return keyFactory.generateSecret(keySpec);
}

private static IvParameterSpec generateIV(Cipher cipher) throws Exception {
    byte [] ivBytes = new byte[cipher.getBlockSize()];
    random.nextBytes(ivBytes);
    return new IvParameterSpec(ivBytes);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

It is important to understand that the result of encryption is binary data and that it cannot be treated as if it were text.

If you want to convert the encrypted data to text, then you should hex-encode it, for example with a library like [this one from apache commons](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Hex.html). In most cases, it is not ever necessary to ever use a text version of the encrypted data.

And in particular, your way of converting the byte array through an intervening String certainly doesn't do what you intended.

Given your code, you will want to change your `decrypt` method to take a `byte[]` and pass the `byte[] encryptedtext` to it.

Comment: I need a way to use string